# How to use Nested Rules in LESS for Custom Checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I have used custom Check-Box with simple css rules and Font Awesome Icon:

[Custom Check Box JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/siddharthjogia/51909oee/)

But these rules applies to all checkbox in a page.

For this problem, I found that, .LESS file can produce nested css rules.

So I have made a LESS file and put custom check box rules under one class `custom-checkbox`.

But it does not working.

Here is my sample code for LESS file:

```
/*** Custom Checkboxes START ***/
.custom-checkbox {
  input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
  }
  /* to hide the checkbox itself */
  input[type=checkbox] + label:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  input[type=checkbox] + label:before {
    content: "\f096";
  }
  /* unchecked icon */
  input[type=checkbox] + label:before {
    letter-spacing: 10px;
  }
  /* space between checkbox and label */

  input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {
    content: "\f046";
  }
  /* checked icon */
  input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {
    letter-spacing: 8px;
  }
  /* allow space for check mark */
}
/*** Custom Checkboxes END ***/
```

I want to apply only single `custom-checkbox` class defined in LESS file. which customize that check box only. How can achieve the same thing given in my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/siddharthjogia/51909oee/)?

Comment: It would be useful if you also provide the HTML code of the variant with nesting that you tried (as there're actually two ways: to do this in html, i.e. by adding `.custom-checkbox` class to the checkbox element itself OR by wrapping it with another element of the custom class. Thus depending on that your CSS should produce either `input.custom-checkbox` or `.custom-checkbox input` selectors.)

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with the Less Code. As seven-phases-max has mentioned, as long as your markup is right the CSS should work (like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/51909oee/1/)).

Comment: E.g.: [demo](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/eNQBPK?editors=110) for both variants (w/o simplified things too much to not confuse you).

Comment: Thanks @seven-phases-max and Harry for your comments.
By wrapping checkbox and label into a div element, this problem can be solved. But still I don't know if everything is correct then why .LESS file is not working.!!!

Comment: @seven-phases-max Thanks for solving .LESS code. I got my answer.

Comment: So if you did this by wrapping, the code in your Q is already correct (in my demo I only deverbosed it slightly, but the resulting CSS is the same).

Comment: Yes you are correct and that is where I made a mistake. Actually the css rules are little bit complex for me and I am new in .LESS type of design style. But now from your demo, I got the way, how to do that thing.